# How does a "power set" work on proper classes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand what the notion of "power set" means when we consider a class $A$ that is not a set (a proper class), where the definition of the "power set" of $A$ is:

> $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{x: x \subseteq A\}$

I have a theorem that states:

> If $A$ is a set then $x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \iff x \subseteq A$.

So, unless this theorem was intentionally written in a confusing way, this seems to indicate that one of these implications breaks for $A$ being a proper class. But that also seems to contradict the definition. So... what's going on here?

Another piece of information I have is that $\mathcal{P(U)} = \mathcal{U}$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is the universe in which we are working (and $\mathcal{U}$ is not a set).

So what exactly does it mean to take the power set of a proper class?

Comment: It's important to note that if you're working in a theory like ZF, and $A$ is a proper class, $\exists x(x=A)$ is false. So you can't even apply an instance of the power set axiom to $A$ to start with. In ZF, proper classes are a figure of speech, and not actually things in the theory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a theory that doesn't allow proper classes to be elements (as I suspect you are), the best we can do is to construct the class of sub*sets* of $A$. This class will be a proper class, so we should probably call it the *power class* of $A$. Your theorem will then apply for sets $x$.

Note also that $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{U})$ is the class of subsets of $\mathcal{U}$, i.e. $\mathcal{U}$ itself as required. If this seems at odd with Cantor's theorem, note the latter's proof constructs something that would be a proper class and hence no element of $\mathcal{U}$, so the theorem doesn't work for proper classes' power classes.

You might want to modify these ideas to interpret the union of a proper class, $\bigcup A$.

Comment: A bit late to the game here. So if $\mathcal{C}$ is a class of subsets of an underlying set $X$, i.e. $Y\in\mathcal{C}$ implies $Y\subseteq X$, is it correct to define the set of all subsets of $\mathcal{C}$, denoted as $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$, as $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})=\{y:y\in Y \text{ for some }Y\in\mathcal{C}\}$. If so $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set and not a class (as required), and furthermore $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$. Also how does this defintion (of a set) differ from the class of all subsets of $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @dandar In your example the power set axiom implies $\mathcal{C}$ is a set, as is $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$. However, $\{y|\exists Y\in\mathcal{C}(y\in Y)\}$ is an in general different set, $\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ by the union axiom. In particular, if $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ then $\bigcup\mathcal{C}\subseteq X$.

Comment: +1 for informative answer and (if I could give it) +1 for speed of response. So a set $A$ is *by definition* a set if and only if there exists a set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ which is defined in the power set axiom? Now I learnt in basic set theory that if $A=\{a,b,c\}$ that $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\},A\}$ is a *class*.

Comment: But you are saying because, say, $\{a,c\}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ implies and is implied by $\{a,c\}=\{\{a\},\{a,c\}\}\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, and this holds for all elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$, that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ satisfies the power set axiom and so is a set? So applying this logic to $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ we arrive at your claim that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ are in fact both sets?

Comment: I now see what you mean by $\bigcup\mathcal{C}:=\{y:\exists Y\in\mathcal{C},y\in Y\}\not=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ in general. For instance $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{C}=\{a,\{b,c\}\}\subset X$ give $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c\},\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\},\mathcal{C}\}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c\},X,\mathcal{C}\}$ and $\bigcup\mathcal{C}=\{a\}\cup\{b,c\}=X$. Thus $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})\not=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Furthermore, as you state, since $\mathcal{P}(X)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\},X\}$ then $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\bigcup\mathcal{C}\subseteq X$. Previous to this new knowledge, where necessary I always thought of a class as a set whose elements are sets - I never realised you could formally prove it is a set. So....what classes are *not* sets (proper classes?). This possibility of proper classes then prevents Russell's paradox? I realise I am into dangerously philsophical things here (for me anyway)!

Comment: @dandar You have a few misconceptions. Sets are classes that are elements of some class; it's classes that are more general. A set's power set is a set.

Comment: It is not surprising I have misconceptions about this concept. Thank you for your patience. So a class $\mathcal{C}$ is not a set - i.e. there exists no power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ of this class by which to prove $\mathcal{C}$ is a set?

Comment: @dandar In the example you gave, $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ so $\mathcal{C}$ is a set.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So $\mathcal{P}(X)$ being viewed as a class, and $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ means, by definition (power set axiom) that $\mathcal{C}$ is a set? In exactly the same way, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ being viewed as a class (i.e the class of subsets of the class $\mathcal{P}(X)$) and $\mathcal{P}(X)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ means by definition that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is also a set? Thus $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is both a class and a set?

Comment: @dandar The easiest approach is that if $X$ is a set so are $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (that's an axiom), as is $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ (same axiom), whence so is $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Many thanks I think this is slowly sinking in. I will go and study some of these axioms and reflect on this.